# I want to add an arraylist that contains jlabels of images to my applet screen

Tags: java, arraylist, jlabel, japplet, imageicon

So what i want to do is instead display a string hello world "("Hello World",i*100,y)" i want to display my jlabels which is in an ArrayList

```
public class FruitWarUI extends JApplet implements Runnable{     

public int WIDTH = 500, HEIGHT = 725, y=0;
BufferedImage screen = new BufferedImage(WIDTH,HEIGHT, 4);      


@Override
public void init(){
    new Thread(this).start();

}

@Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
    screen.getGraphics().clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    for(int i=0; i<=5; i++) screen.getGraphics().drawString("Hello World",i*100,y);
    g.drawImage(screen, 0, 0, this);
} 

@Override
public void run(){              
    try{ 
        for(y=0; y<700; y++){ 
            Thread.sleep(10); 
            repaint();  
        } 
        run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } 
    }
```

Comment: And ..what is your question?  BTW - Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: Cool. Then read the Swing tutorial and learn how to add and lay out components inside a container.

Comment: in my code u see drawString("Hello World",i*100,y); rite, i want to remove that and pass in an arraylist of jlabels, so instead of displaying hello world it displays my jlabels on the applet screen...got it?

Comment: Cool. Then read the Swing tutorial and learn how to add and lay out components inside a container. You don't need to paint anything when using Swing components. You just add them to the applet (or other container), and use a layout manager to tell Swing how they should be laid out. The Swing tutorial explains that.

Comment: i know to used swing but the trouble i have is how to display jlabel on my applet and giving them the same falling effect

Comment: Tip:  Add @JBNizet (or whoever - the `@` is important) to *notify* them of a new comment.  BTW - I suspect that both `JLabel` & layouts are entirely unsuited to this task,  it seems to need [custom painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) & at that stage, you only need an `Image`, rather than a component such as a `JLabel`.  BTW - For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).